# Using apply.rolling function over multiple columns

Tags: r, zoo, performanceanalytics, rollapply

In `zoo` package, while using `rollapply` function, we get an logical option '`by.column = TRUE/FALSE`'. If `TRUE`, `FUN` is applied to each column separately.

However, in `apply.rolling` function of `PerformanceAnalytics` package I don't see any such option. While trying to the following:

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

data(managers)

apply.rolling(managers[,1:10,drop=FALSE], FUN="mean", width=36)
```

It give me calculation of only first column. Can someone please tell me how can I run this calculation over all the columns in the dataset.

Comment: Sorry David, I am new to R and lack programming skills unlike you. Hence sometimes naive like me find it difficult to understand technical programming language. Thank you very much for your helpful response.

Comment: Sorry for my sarcastic response :) There is nothing about programming here really, just start reading documentation before using functions. Google "PerformanceAnalytics pckg r pdf"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there something wrong with just using `rollapply()`? `apply.rolling()` is just a wrapper over it.

```
rollapply(managers, FUN = mean, width = 36, by.column = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your solution. For some reason, @Jairaj Gupta asks `apply.rolling`...

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` function `apply.rolling` on `xts` object:

```
apply(managers, 2, function(x){apply.rolling(x, FUN="mean", width=36)})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the help page for `apply.rolling` it says:

```
Details

Wrapper function for rollapply to hide some of the complexity of managing **single-column zoo objects**.
```

I think that means the intent is to not use this on objects with multiple columns. It is a simplified wrapper which allows you to not have to type out all the various optional parameters for `rollapply()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `lapply()` with `rollapply()` from the `zoo` package to perform your rolling function over multiple columns. In the following code, I select all columns except the first (`select(-1)`) and perform my rolling function over the remaining columns.

In `dplyr()` code:

```
m3v %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  lapply(function(x){rollapply(x, 
                           width=14, 
                           FUN=function(x){sum(x, na.rm=T)},
                           partial = T, fill = 0
                           )}) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```